# How to change "rest" in server.xml from restful path

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I read in adobe blog that from a rest url mypath.com/rest/somapp/app I can customize "rest" text from server.xml. I opened server.xml from cfusion\runtime\conf folder but do not any place where I can change it. How and where I can change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not in the `server.xml` file but rather the `web.xml` file. Specifically `{cfroot}/cfusion/wwwroot/WEB-INF/web.xml` and you will need to restart the ColdFusion service after making changes.

From the blog post here - [Changing the default URL pattern for REST Services in ColdFusion 10](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2012/02/20/changing-the-default-url-pattern-for-rest-services-in-coldfusion-10/):

> The way ColdFusion handles REST-enabled services is via a pre-defined Servlet Mapping in web.xml that looks like this :-
>
> ```
> <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_15">
>     <servlet-name>CFRestServlet</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>`
> ```
>
> This Servlet Mapping has a URL Pattern which tells CF that any URL starting with “/rest” is to be treated as a REST service. However, if you feel the need to change it to something more appropriate, you simply change the url-pattern in {cfroot}/cfusion/wwwroot/WEB-INF/web.xml and restart ColdFusion Server.

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to change uriworkermap.properties file too?

Comment: Not according to the blog post I referenced.

Comment: According to http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html#articlecontentAdobe_text_3 you _do_ need to change the uriworkermapp.properties file too.